# Wrong UITableViewAutomaticDimension height, only on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The height of my tableview cell is calculated automatically

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and it works great on all devices, except iPhone 5. Tried this on actual device and in simulator with same result:

[image]

Any ideas why is it happening? iOS 10.3.1

Comment: check your constraints.

Comment: try tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10

Comment: i agree with @MaheshDangar

Comment: @TmGoyani >it works great on all devices, except iPhone 5. How can constraints be the reason?

Comment: @Edward if you want to achieve dynamic height in all devices then you must have set proper constraints and return  'UITableViewAutomaticDimension'  in heightForRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is only available on iOS 11.

Use a real value instead :

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
} else {
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
}
```

Comment: no, it is just a constraints problem not versioning problem cuz UITableViewAutomaticDimension is available after ios 5.0

Comment: You're talking about setting 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension' in 'rowHeight' not 'estimatedRowHeight'. This is new in iOS11. Please read the answer properly.

Answer (score 2):

The estimated row height should be the average height of your cells'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set value for estimated row height that will be your minimum rowHeight. 
Below is an example...

> tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44;